# Mobile menu for Joomla site not behaving properly

Tags: jquery, css, joomla, responsive-design

I've been working on a mobile menu which expands to reveal sub-menu items, and it looked like it was working fine until I noticed some strange behaviour.

URL: yorkshirefrench.com

It seems the jquery which opens the sub menu only works when I'm away from the homepage. If I open the homepage on my phone or on a computer, the mobile menu opens but the menu items with a sub menu do not expand. When I look in the inspector nothing is being changed for the child UL.

When I do the same thing from other pages on the site, these all work fine.

Please help!

Comment: For example, if you use http://yorkshirefrench.com/about instead, the menu works fine.

Comment: You have error in the javascript in the home page that's why your menu accordion not working.

Comment: Here's the error TypeError: jQuery(...).show(...).nivoSlider is not a function

Comment: Looks like my jQuery for the accordion is conflicting with the Nivo slider (which is no longer displaying). I'm an extreme beginner with jQuery does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I've got the slider working again by removing the link to jQuery from the head. Saw similar conflicts with nivo slider / jQuery elsewhere, solutions mentioned jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: Could this noConflict fix my problem? The code I've currently got for the mobile menu is here:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

   jQuery( "#mobilemenu" ).click(function() {
      jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
      jQuery("ul#spring li ul" ).hide();
      jQuery("ul#spring li.active ul" ).show();
      jQuery( "#spring" ).toggle( "slow"); 
    });
  
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
    if(jQuery(window).width() < 800) { // set max width of mobile menu 
     jQuery( "ul#spring li" ).click(function() {
        jQuery("ul#spring li ul" ).hide("slow");
        jQuery('ul', this).toggle("slow");
     });
    }
  });

 
</script>

Comment: Why not remove the Nivo slider because you said you not using it. It will fix you problem if you do that.

Comment: I am using the nivo slider on the homepage. I could possibly swap this for an orbit slide show but I fear this may have a similar conflict?

Comment: Maybe just arrange you're javascript to remove the conflict. If still don't fix put noConflict or just use other slider.